# Float a div to the right when screen is wide, stack when screen is narrow

Tags: html, css

In the code below I want the following conditions to hold:

1. The pink div always spans the viewport.
2. The pink div's text is always centered in the viewport.
3. The blue div floats to the right when the screen is "sufficiently wide."
4. The blue div stacks below the pink div when the screen is not "sufficiently wide."
5. The blue div spans the viewport and its text is centered when stacked.
6. The solution should be pure CSS.

Here's my current pass:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#parent {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height:  20px;
}
#center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: pink;
    text-align: center;
}
#placeholder {
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 500px;
}
#right {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="center">This text should always be centered in the VIEWPORT</div>
    <div id="right">this text should float to the right</div>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what it currently looks like when the screen is wide (correct):

[image: wide]

Here's what it looks like when the screen is narrow (incorrect):

[image: narrow]

Here's what it should look like when the screen is narrow:

[image: narrow goal]

Comment: Use media query to adjust css based on screen size http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: I did know about that possibility.  In your estimation, is that the current standard way of approaching a layout problem like this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/v7k4oky8/4/

edited fiddle for proper text align

```
 body{margin: 0;}
    #parent {
        position: relative;
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        height:  20px;
    }
    #center {
       float: left;
       margin: auto;
       width: calc(100% - 500px);
       background-color: pink;
       padding-left: 250px;
    }
    #right {
        float: left;
        background-color: blue;
        width: 250px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 610px){
        #right {width: 100%; text-align: center;}
        #center {width: 100%;}
    }
```

Comment: You beat me to it yet again Adam haha +1

Comment: I don't think this is correct actually.  If you narrow the screen, the text in the pink div does not remain centered in the viewport.  I believe the {position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; margin: auto; } trick is necessary.

Comment: @JoeyJoeJoeJuniorShabadoo it depends, do you want it centered to the screen or to the pink box, i can do both using this method

Comment: @JoeyJoeJoeJuniorShabadoo look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/v7k4oky8/5/

Comment: I left out the #center in the in the media query, my bad

Comment: This has given me some very useful insights, but the text is not centered in the viewport.  Using this strategy, there are 250px before the start of the text and 250px + the distance from the end of the text to the start of the right div.  To better see this effect, change the text in the center div to something short.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me to keep a spinning image in the same location on each side of the screen. Adjust left / right and top to position each div on either side.

```
<div class="col" style="overflow: none; z-index: 9999;">
    <div id="spinning-circle" class="row" style="position:absolute; top:750px; left:-25px; z-index:1; width: auto!important;">
        <img src="../certdb/images/left-bubble.png">
    </div>
    <div id="spinning-circle" class="row" style="position:absolute; top:250px; right:-145px; z-index:1; width: auto!important;">
        <img src="../certdb/images/right-bubble.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

BODY ->

```
.Site {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

Page Container ->

```
  .Site-content {
    flex: 1;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    max-width: 1500px;
    min-height: 80%;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/znLv6peg/11/

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution.  I don't know if this is best.  For one thing, it requires you to set explicit heights.  I set the defaults for mobile and altered for large screens per a best practice I read somewhere.  I noticed that if you put this in JSFiddle it doesn't work properly, but it does if you use it in a browser (only Firefox tested).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{margin: 0;}
#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:  40px;
    text-align:center;
}
#center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: pink;
}
#right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #00FFFF;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    #parent {
        height: 20px;
    }
    #right {
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        top: 0;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="center">This text should always be centered in the VIEWPORT</div>
    <div id="right">this text should float to the right</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would love to know WHY this is sub-optimal.